# What is the word that describes experiences different from the norm?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I am trying to think of the word that describes someone’s experience that may differ from the norm. There may be a group of these experiences, but they are not scientifically measured or counted. Such as, every time I go outside, I get stung by a bee. I have a cousin who gets stung by a bee every time they go outside. The general understanding is that you will be safe from being stung by a bee. Your personal experiences tell you something different.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample sentence? I've closed this question for now since it needs this key detail, but if you [edit] I can reopen it.

Comment: 'Atypical' fits most cases.

Comment: @Sue Are you thinking of **anecdotal experience**?

Comment: Aberrant could be a possibility.